# Trying to susbcribe to PairCreated events from UniswapV2 Factory in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethereum

I have previously used this code to get events from PancakeSwapV2 factory on the Binance Smart Chain. I'd like now to use this code to get events from UniswapV2 factory on the Ethereum blockchain but I get the following error :

```
(node:3544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f ", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.4.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:187:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:196:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:199:21)
    at C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:101:32
    at step (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\aaaa\WebstormProjects\web3test\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To
 terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here's the source code I'm trying to reuse :

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const ethers = require('ethers');

const INFURA_BASE_URL = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/';
const INFURA_API_KEY = 'REPLACE';
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_BASE_URL + INFURA_API_KEY));

const privateKey = "REPLACE";
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)
console.log(account.address)

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/REPLACE');
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
const account2 = wallet.connect(provider);

const addresses = {
    WETH: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
    factory: '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f ',
    router: '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ',
    recipient: account.address
};

//console.log(provider)

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
    addresses.factory,
    [
        'event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)',
        'function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair)'
    ],
    account2
);

factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => { }
```

Would you know what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I'm approaching the solution with this piece of code :

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

let web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/cc44823998a0412294a47680xxxxxxxx")
);

let abi = JSON.parse('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f');

//web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)

    instance.getPastEvents(
        "allEvents",
        {fromBlock: "12908000", toBlock: "12908094"},
        (errors, events) => {
            if (!errors) {
                //console.log('it is ok')
                //console.log(events)
             }
        }
    ).then(r => {
        console.log(r)
    });
```